# Which files does vim get environment variables from?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to duplicate the vim environment on a Debian machine that displays filename, number of lines, number of characters, line, column. I looked at `~/.vimrc` but didn't see any options relevant. `/etc/vim/vimrc` basically contains nothing except for looking for `/etc/vim/vimrc.local` which doesn't exist. What else set environment for vim?

Comment: Does `:help runtimepath` contain the information you're looking for?

Answer (score 5):

Environment variables have nothing to do with this and you are wasting your time looking for non-existing files.

Assuming you have two machines, A and B, where A is the machine with the settings you want to duplicate to B…

1. Start a new session on A:

   ```
   $ vim
   ```
2. Use `:help :mkvimrc` to dump the current settings to a file:

   ```
   :mkvimrc mysettings.vim
   ```
3. Review the file:

   ```
   :e mysettings.vim
   ```

   Some of it will probably not matter to you or you may want to change a few things here and there. Either way, this is a good time for looking up the documentation for any line that you may not understand.
4. Move the file to B and save it as `$HOME/.vimrc`.

If you want to dig deeper into the subject, `:help startup` has *everything*.

Note that Vim has a mechanism for setting options on a filetype basis. Those settings won't be part of the dump for, I hope, obvious reasons.

Comment: Thanks. This works for me except that I had to save it as `$HOME/.vimrc` on B.